# how query using oracle

Tags: oracle

In company C1, the only lead manager is LM1. There are two senior managers, SM1 and SM2, under LM1. There is one manager, M1, under senior manager SM1. There are two employees, E1 and E2, under manager M1.

In company C2, the only lead manager is LM2. There is one senior manager, SM3, under LM2. There are two managers, M2 and M3, under senior manager SM3. There is one employee, E3, under manager M2, and another employee, E4, under manager, M3.

**expected outcome:**

C1 Monika 1 2 1 2

C2 Samantha 1 1 2 2

**company table:**

[image]

**Lead_Manager table:**

[image]

**Senior_Manager table:**

[image]

**Manager table:**

[image]

**Employee table:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
select count(company.company_code) from company
join lead_manager on company.company_code = lead_manager.company_code
join senior_manager on company.company_code = senior_manager.company_code
join manager on company.company_code = manager.company_code
join employee on company.company_code = employee.company_code
order by company.company_code;
```

**current outup:** 117637

The issue is in my first line. I don't know how what I should be

**what i tried:**

- `select * from company`
- `select count(distinct lead_manager.company_code), count(distinct senior_manager.company_code), count(distinct manager.company_code), count(distinct employee.company_code) from company`

Comment: Do not post images for data in the question. Include data as text.

Comment: Why are you using 5 tables and duplicating data across all of them? You can probably store all the data in one table (or maybe two) with a hierarchical data structure and keep the data in third-normal form.

Comment: @MT0 Im a front-end guy trying to learn. How would I go about doing this.

Comment: You join by the company code only, while you explicitly specify, for example: there are two **managers**, M2 and M3, **under senior manager** SM3. So to relate manager to the lead manager you need to find a senior manager and find (join) a lead manager of this particular senior manager. You will go this way when you describe the relationship in general words, but why it is not expressed in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change your data model and use a single hierarchical table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id         NUMBER(8,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  company_id VARCHAR2(20),
  manager_id REFERENCES employees,
  name       VARCHAR2(20),
  job_title  VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Then you can store the employees for `C1` as:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees (id, company_id, manager_id, name, job_title)
SELECT 1, 'C1', NULL, 'Monica', 'Founder'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C1', 1,    'Alice',  'Lead Manager'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C1', 2,    'Betty',  'Senior Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'C1', 2,    'Carol',  'Senior Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'C1', 3,    'Debra',  'Manager'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'C1', 5,    'Emily',  'Employee'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'C1', 5,    'Fiona',  'Employee'       FROM DUAL;
```

and get your output using the hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT company_id,
       MAX(CASE job_title WHEN 'Founder'        THEN name END) AS founder,
       COUNT(CASE job_title WHEN 'Lead Manager'   THEN id END) AS num_lead_manager,
       COUNT(CASE job_title WHEN 'Senior Manager' THEN id END) AS num_senior_manager,
       COUNT(CASE job_title WHEN 'Manager'        THEN id END) AS num_manager,
       COUNT(CASE job_title WHEN 'Employee'       THEN id END) AS num_employee
FROM   employees e
START WITH manager_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = manager_id
GROUP BY company_id
```

Which outputs:

> | COMPANY_ID | FOUNDER | NUM_LEAD_MANAGER | NUM_SENIOR_MANAGER | NUM_MANAGER | NUM_EMPLOYEE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | C1 | Monica | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e6adc89e799f79e2632bd10114ccd34b)*

Comment: company_code
*
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined @MT0

Comment: @jgrewal Updated with a hierarchical data structure.